# How to make this text fill animation in flutter

Tags: html, css, flutter, css-animations, flutter-animation

I want to make a flutter timer app which will fill the screen from bottom to top with a color. I think i can do that by incrementing the size of the container with respect to time but i want the text as shown in the image. Please someone help me with this.

[image: Animation image]

It changes the color of the text as the size of the container, which fills the screen, increases.

Comment: For now I'm gonna give a constant value to it in the code itself, but i will change it later

Answer (score 1):

I can offer a solution for css. The timer counter will be displayed with rule `content: ''`, with a cycle of 10 seconds and a delay of 1 second before this animation starts.

```
.timer:after {
    content: "0";
    animation: timer 10s 1s forwards;
}
```

The complete css code shows how 10 seconds are distributed over a percentage of 100%.

```
@keyframes timer {
    10% {
        content: "1";
    }

    ...

    100% {
        content: "10";
    }
}
```

I used rule `mix-blend-mode: difference` to invert the background color.

> The `mix-blend-mode` CSS property sets how an element's content should blend with the content of the element's parent and the element's background.

I changed the height of the dynamic background element using rule `top`, and animated it in a similar way using rule `animation` and `@keyframes`.

```
@keyframes background_top {
    from {
        top: 100%;
    }
    to {
        top: 0%;
    }
}
```

> The `@keyframes` rule sets keyframes when animating an element. A keyframe is an element's properties (transparency, color, position, etc.) that should be applied to an element at a given moment in time. Thus, animation is a smooth transition of style properties from one keyframe to another. The calculation of intermediate values between such frames is taken over by the browser.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background: lightgrey;
    position: relative;
}

.background {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: brown;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    animation: background_top 10s 1s forwards;
}

.timer:after {
    content: "0";
    animation: timer 10s 1s forwards;
    font-size: 10em;
    color: lightseagreen;
}

@keyframes timer {
    10% {
        content: "1";
    }
    20% {
        content: "2";
    }
    30% {
        content: "3";
    }
    40% {
        content: "4";
    }
    50% {
        content: "5";
    }
    60% {
        content: "6";
    }
    70% {
        content: "7";
    }
    80% {
        content: "8";
    }
    90% {
        content: "9";
    }
    100% {
        content: "10";
    }
}

@keyframes background_top {
    from {
        top: 100%;
    }
    to {
        top: 0%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="timer"></div>
    <div class="background"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah this is what i need but in flutter, thanks for the css though

Comment: @RahulGupta, no problem.

Comment: Can you explain how this works or share some article or anything about it

Comment: @RahulGupta, I gave a description.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way of doing this in flutter with CustomPaint.
The only thing you have to change is the StatelessWidget to a StatefulWidget so that the animation is possible, however I would recommend using something like [hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) this package can make animation pretty simple.

```
class TextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: CustomPaint(
      size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
      painter: TimerPainter(text: "6", height: 500),
    ));
  }
}

class TimerPainter extends CustomPainter {
  TimerPainter({required this.text, required this.height});

  final String text;
  final double height;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // ========================================== TextPainter

    final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        text: TextSpan(
          text: text,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.greenAccent,
            fontSize: 500,
          ),
        ))
      ..layout();
    textPainter.paint(
        canvas,
        Offset(size.width / 2 - textPainter.width / 2,
            size.height / 2 - textPainter.height / 2));

    // ============================================== Rect

    final rectPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.greenAccent
      ..blendMode=BlendMode.difference;
    canvas.drawRect(
        Offset(0, size.height / 2) & Size(size.width, height), rectPaint);
    final rectPaint2 = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..blendMode=BlendMode.difference;
    canvas.drawRect(
        Offset(0, size.height / 2) & Size(size.width, height), rectPaint2);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

[this is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y9Ip.png)

Comment: I am new to flutter so it will be a great help if you can explain it or share me some type of blog or video or anything

Comment: of course you could watch this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdhoIQqS2z0&t=565s for animations with hooks and if you want to learn the basics of hooks look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1DUBgIsCv8&t=321s. I hope this can help you